# Azure WebApp and docker-compose in Linux

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webapp2, azure-webapps

I have a WebApp that runs in Linux Service Plan as docker-compose. My config is:

```
version: '3'
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  web-site:
    image: server.azurecr.io/site/site-production:latest
    container_name: web-site
    networks:
      - my-network
  nginx:
    image: server.azurecr.io/nginx/nginx-production:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network
```

And I realize that my app is sometimes freezing for a while (usually less than 1 minute) and when I get to check on Diagnose (Linux - Number of Running Containers per Host) I can see this:

[image: Containers]

How could it be possible to have 20+ containers running?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide details on your app service and app service plan configuration. Are multiple sites connected to the app service plan?

Comment: Also, note that "networks" is unsupported and ignored on App Service.

Comment: Sorry, it's running within a B3 Linux Service Plan. It has http2 and Always on enabled. This service Plan has 6 apps running within it.

Comment: Try to switch to a P1V2 plan to see if you'll have the same limits as none are stated in the services limits page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new service plan (P2v2) for my app (and nothing else) and my app (which has just two containers - .net 3.1 and nginx) and it shows 4 containers... but this is not a problem for me... at all...

The problem I've found in Application Insigths was about a method that retrieves a blob to serve an image... blobs are really fast for uploads and downloads but they are terrible for search... my method was checking if the blob exists before sending it to api and this (assync) proccess was blocking my api responses... I just removed the check and my app is running as desired (all under 1sec - almost all under 250ms reponse).

Thanks for you help.